# Ubuntu 18.04 Video Driver for AOpen DEX4502

Tags: drivers, graphics, video, intel-graphics, intel

That ancient AOpen DEX4502 hardware has an Intel® GM45+ICH9M chipset with GMA X4500MHD graphics engine.

I could not install Ubuntu 18.04 without using that nomodeset option.
Now Ubuntu is booting but the machine runs really hot and I was hoping I could solve this by using the proper video driver.

Inxi is saying the driver is 'fbdev' and also mentions 'modesetting' and 'vesa' as being unloaded. I was hoping I could find and install an 'intel' driver that would make use of the machine hardware.

Do I need to update the kernel to a version that has built-in support for that hardware? Am I better off using an older Ubuntu version? I know it used to run some older version without overheating.

`inxi -G` outputs the following:

```
Graphics:  Card: Intel Mobile 4 Series Integrated Graphics Controller
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
           drivers: fbdev (unloaded: modesetting,vesa)
           Resolution: 1600x1200@77.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 128 bits)
           version: 3.3 Mesa 18.0.0-rc5
```

After creating that 20-intel.conf file as explained [there](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/enable-dri3-by-default-in-18-04/1253/8).
Inxi shows `drivers: fbdev,intel (unloaded: modesetting,vesa)`.
Enabling modesetting then still prevents it from booting up.
I guess I'll try disabling `fbdev` but to be honest I have no idea what I'm doing.

After removing the `fbdev` package and a reboot inxi is now showing:
`drivers: vesa,intel (unloaded: modesetting)`
So I'll try removing `vesa`.

Removing the vesa driver prevented me to even access the terminal and I had to do a re-installation. So I'm guessing that '20-intel.conf' is not helping much other than somehow showing `intel` in the drivers list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try removing nomodeset from the kernel line in grub and replace it with 'acpi_os=linux'. If that gives you a blank screen, use the brightness adjustment on the display to make it brighter. Also post the output of 'grep -i w|e|i915 /var/log/Xorg.0.log.

Comment: I meant the 'linux' line in grub.

Comment: @Brian I tried the suggested grub changes without joy. It hangs on a purple screen while booting, certainly failing to init graphics. That grep command does not find anything either.